# how to replace dots inside quote in sentence with regex

Tags: regex

lets say there is something like this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. `"Vestibulum interdum dolor nec sapien blandit a suscipit arcu fermentum. Nullam lacinia ipsum vitae enim consequat iaculis quis in augue. Phasellus fermentum congue blandit. Donec laoreet, ipsum et vestibulum vulputate, risus augue commodo nisi, vel hendrerit sem justo sed mauris."` Phasellus ut nunc neque, id varius nunc. In enim lectus, blandit et dictum at, molestie in nunc. Vivamus eu ligula sed augue pretium tincidunt sit amet ac nisl. `"Morbi eu elit diam, sed tristique nunc."`

to be something like this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. `"Vestibulum interdum dolor nec sapien blandit a suscipit arcu fermentum[dot] Nullam lacinia ipsum vitae enim consequat iaculis quis in augue[dot] Phasellus fermentum congue blandit[dot] Donec laoreet, ipsum et vestibulum vulputate, risus augue commodo nisi, vel hendrerit sem justo sed mauris[dot]"` Phasellus ut nunc neque, id varius nunc. In enim lectus, blandit et dictum at, molestie in nunc. Vivamus eu ligula sed augue pretium tincidunt sit amet ac nisl. `"Morbi eu elit diam, sed tristique nunc[dot]"`

i somehow found a regex to select all the "{sentence}" with `"(.)+?"` or use them like

`regex('"(.)+?"','[sentence]')`

but can we do something like replace the dots inside a group?. so i can get the output like above example?

Comment: `.` is the character for "any character".  if you want a literal dot, you need to escape it like `\.`

Comment: no thats just an example of my progress. i was thinking that we can use two time regex, so we can do something like search for `\.` for each group then convert them into [dot]. but still maybe we can do it in one preg replace function

Comment: What technology do you use? I don't think regexps will be able to suit your needs on their own.

Comment: php ruby nodejs i think they are all the same sp00m they have two-three args, like `output = preg_replace('/regex/', what you want to regex, '')` will be `what you want` but im currently using node.

Comment: @user1780413 Yeah, but the idea is to replace nested dots until the string doesn't contain nested dots anymore.

Comment: @sp00m can you give me an example with javascript or in php? or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure regexps are able to suit your needs on their own.

You should implement an algorithm that replaces nested dots until the string doesn't contain nested dots anymore.

For example in PHP:

```
$string = 'He asked "Please." while she answered "No. Or maybe yes."';
var_dump($string);
while(preg_match('/"[^"]*\.[^"]*"/', $string)) {
    $string = preg_replace('/("[^"]*)\.([^"]*")/', '$1[dot]$2', $string);
}
var_dump($string);
```

which prints:

```
string 'He asked "Please." while she answered "No. Or maybe yes."' (length=57)
string 'He asked "Please[dot]" while she answered "No[dot] Or maybe yes[dot]"' (length=69)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.

```
echo
preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\\\)"(.+?)((?<!\\\)")~',
/*
Pattern:
--------
(?<!\\\)"       a double quote not preceded by a backward (escaping) slash
(.+?)           anything (with min 1 char.) between condition above and below
((?<!\\\)")     a double quote not preceded by a backward (escaping) slash
*/
// for anything that matches the above pattern
// the following function is called
create_function('$m',
'return preg_replace("~\.~","[dot]",$m[0]);'),
// which replaces each dot with [dot] and returns the match
$str);
```

**EDIT:** Added explanations in comments.

Comment: Are you asking for pattern and/or code explanation? Let me know if that's the case. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @inhan Of course you should explain your code if it's not trivial enough. How should we learn otherwise?

Comment: @sp00m I was unsure if OP was asking particularly this or how to use this PHP function in general.

Comment: nope im translateing into node.js code, however i think people need to know about this too.

Comment: You should use the Javascript tag in your question since several important specs do not apply to all regex flavors such as lookbehind and recursive patterns. I had to post a separate answer for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`(\"[^\.]*)\.([^\"]*)` to `\1[dot]\2`

works well in my editor, but sometimes $ is used instead of \ in replacement (e.g. in php)

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript I would just do a basic replace:

```
str = str.replace(/".+?"/g,function(m) {
    return m.replace(/\./g,'[dot]');
});
```